# Why MongoDB is fetching documents from disk after a sort even when the used index contains all fields on the query

Tags: database, mongodb, sorting, indexing

Apparently MongoDB is fetching all documents from disk to be able to fulfill a query after a sort.

To illustrate the issue we can insert the following documents with a progress and a date into a foo collection:

```
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 1, "progress" : "A", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-01T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 2, "progress" : "A", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-02T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 3, "progress" : "A", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-03T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 4, "progress" : "B", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-04T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 5, "progress" : "B", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-05T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 6, "progress" : "B", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-06T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 7, "progress" : "C", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-07T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 8, "progress" : "C", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-08T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 9, "progress" : "C", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-09T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 10, "progress" : "D", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-10T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 11, "progress" : "D", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-11T07:52:40.831Z")});
db.foo.insert({ "_id" : 12, "progress" : "D", "date" : ISODate("2017-12-12T07:52:40.831Z")});
```

Then create the following index:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({date : 1, progress:1});
```

As the date is the first field on the index, that can be used to sort by date. The index also contains the progress as the second field. Therefore I would expect a query by progress sorted by date to be able to scan the index and then filter the documents only fetching from disk those that match the query. But instead the `totalDocsExamined` on the `executionStats` show that it fetched the whole collection.

This is how Im running the explain command:

```
db.foo.find({progress:"A"}).sort({ date:-1 }).explain("executionStats")
```

And this is the result:

```
{ 
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1.0, 
        "namespace" : "test.foo", 
        "indexFilterSet" : false, 
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "progress" : {
                "$eq" : "A"
            }
        }, 
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "filter" : {
                "progress" : {
                    "$eq" : "A"
                }
            }, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "date" : 1.0, 
                    "progress" : 1.0
                }, 
                "indexName" : "date_1_progress_1", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "isUnique" : false, 
                "isSparse" : false, 
                "isPartial" : false, 
                "indexVersion" : 1.0, 
                "direction" : "backward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ], 
                    "progress" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        "rejectedPlans" : [

        ]
    }, 
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true, 
        "nReturned" : 3.0, 
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0.0, 
        "totalKeysExamined" : 12.0, 
        "totalDocsExamined" : 12.0, 
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "filter" : {
                "progress" : {
                    "$eq" : "A"
                }
            }, 
            "nReturned" : 3.0, 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
            "works" : 13.0, 
            "advanced" : 3.0, 
            "needTime" : 9.0, 
            "needYield" : 0.0, 
            "saveState" : 0.0, 
            "restoreState" : 0.0, 
            "isEOF" : 1.0, 
            "invalidates" : 0.0, 
            "docsExamined" : 12.0, 
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0.0, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "nReturned" : 12.0, 
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
                "works" : 13.0, 
                "advanced" : 12.0, 
                "needTime" : 0.0, 
                "needYield" : 0.0, 
                "saveState" : 0.0, 
                "restoreState" : 0.0, 
                "isEOF" : 1.0, 
                "invalidates" : 0.0, 
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "date" : 1.0, 
                    "progress" : 1.0
                }, 
                "indexName" : "date_1_progress_1", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "isUnique" : false, 
                "isSparse" : false, 
                "isPartial" : false, 
                "indexVersion" : 1.0, 
                "direction" : "backward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ], 
                    "progress" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                }, 
                "keysExamined" : 12.0, 
                "seeks" : 1.0, 
                "dupsTested" : 0.0, 
                "dupsDropped" : 0.0, 
                "seenInvalidated" : 0.0
            }
        }
    }, 
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "a98a8d9a4d41", 
        "port" : 27017.0, 
        "version" : "3.4.9", 
        "gitVersion" : "876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e"
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

As you can see, `totalDocsExamined` is 12 meaning that the DB had to fetch them from disk. The query used the `date_1_progress_1` index to retrieve the collection in the right order but it failed using the rest of the index to filter the documents with the specified progress. I would expect `totalKeysExamined` to be 12 (scanned all indexes in the collection) but `totalDocsExamined = nReturned = 3` as the used index contained all the required information.

Is there a limitation on how the indexes are used after the index is used by a sort?

On my real data, my collection has a couple of million documents. So the sort requires more than the [32 MB sort limit on Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#operations). That is why I need to use the date first to get the data sorted, and then filter by progress by looking again at the index instead of hitting HDD.

I read [this articule](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields) about how an index is used to return sorted documents. It specifies how you need to use all preceding fields (before the sort field) on the compound index in order for it to actually be used. But it doesn't mention anything about if the proceeding fields on the index (after the sort field). I would expect they could be used for filter purposes without having to hit the HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a code change the introduced this unexpected behaviour after 2.6.

When I was trying plan my indexes, I was trying to follow the "Equality, Sort, Range" rule (incredibly well explained in [this articule](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/)), But it did not mention that the Equality section is mandatory (with the current mongo version 3.6)

There is already a [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15636) in mongo project to fix that, and allow proceeding fields after the sort field, to be looked at by the index instead of going directly to cache/disk even when there is no Equality field before the sort field.

As for now, we need to make sure an Equality Field is in our indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation is not a sort, its the query pattern that is coming into the play. A great detailed explanation can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

Your index starts with Date {Date:1,Progress:1} and Your query fetches progress. Index work in find when the query pattern starts with the way Index pattern has been defined. If you include Date and Progress in query you would see better results or your query pattern order partially or fully satisfies the index(but field in query are in order with index pattern)

Also in projection, you are expecting all the fields of document or the whole document that matches the query criteria, and the created index alone cannot help mongo to fetch all the information.

If you want only index to satisfy the query, you should look at covered queries section of [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).

Comment: I read [this articule](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields) about how an index is used to return sorted documents. It specifies how you need to use all preceding fields (before the sort field) on the compound index in order for it to actually be used. But it doesn't mention anything about if the proceeding fields on the index (after the sort field). I would expect they could be used for filter purposes without having to hit the HDD. Adding this to the main question too.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have created a [compound key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#compound-index)

If you included both indexed keys in your query this wouldn't have happened. Example with the following query:

```
db.foo.find({progress:"A", "date" : {$gte: ISODate("2017-12-03T07:52:40.831+0000")}}).explain("executionStats")
```

it would only check 10 documents instead of 12 since already both documents:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "progress" : "A", 
    "date" : ISODate("2017-12-01T07:52:40.831+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : 2.0, 
    "progress" : "A", 
    "date" : ISODate("2017-12-02T07:52:40.831+0000")
}
```

are excluded from the search.

If you want this query: `db.foo.find({progress:"A"}).sort({ date:-1 }).explain("executionStats")`

to only examine the 3 keys, then you would have to create [multiple single field indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/) instead:

```
db.foo.createIndexes([{date : 1}, {progress:1}]);
```

Comment: Having separate indexes, unfortunately, doesn't help as the chosen index would be `progress_1` and then will do a sort in memory. On my real data, my collection has a couple of million documents. So the sort requires more than the [32 MB sort limit on Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#operations). That is why I wanted to use the date first to get the data sorted, and then filter by progress by looking again at the index instead of hitting HDD.
Adding that fact to the original post.

Comment: @RogelioTonatihuRodriguezRod I don't quite follow you. The [restriction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#restrictions) only appears if the field is not indexed. Then it sorts in memory and the result should be less then 32 mb. Anyway if you want your compound key to work, you'll have to use both fields in every operation. `find` and `sort` are two different operations. You should create a compound index if you'd like to sort on multiple fields, but you seem to want to sort only on one field.

Comment: The issue is that by using separate indexes the progress index can be used to filter first but if there is no compound index it will need to sort it in memory, the date index is not used for the sort. Since the result of that step is not sorted, it will need to be done in memory, and in my case, that amount of information is too big for mongo to sort it, then it takes the other path. It uses the date index as that one is already sorted and starts filtering _after_ the sort. I would expect if the date index already contains the progress info then it would work, but that is not the case.